# Removing specific elements from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `N`. I want to remove elements mentioned in `I` from `N`. But there is an error. I present the expected output.

```
N=[i for i in range(1,11)]
I=[4,9]

N.remove(I)
print(N)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    N.remove(I)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

The expected output is

```
[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to remove a list which is not in N. You either have to call `.remove()` for every element in I or you can do it like this:

```
I = [4, 9]
N = [i for i in range(1, 11) if i not in I]  # [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
```